# Как хранится и манипулируется значение с типом float?

Tags: java, python, задание-на-собеседовании

Сегодня я попытался устроиться на свою первую работу в качестве Python программиста.

Работодатель сам неожиданно позвонил мне и стал тестировать на знание языка по телефону.

Он задал несколько простых вопросов, таких как "чем отличается list от set, и все в таком духе", но затем...

Он спросил меня как в действительности работает тип данных float в Python. Я уточнил, и он ответил что имеет в виду не то что возвращает встроеный метод float() но как именно хранится и манипулируется значение с типом float "под капотом" в Python.

Я не смог ответить на этот вопрос, т. к. Никогда не сталкивался с этим ни в практике ни в теории, после чего мою кандидатуру сразу отклонили.

Чтобы быть более точным и передать приблизительный уровень знаний - я программирую на Java и Python практически каждый день, понимаю основы, ООП, некоторые паттерны.

Есть опыт в несколько проектов кроссплатформенной разработки на Python/Kivy с использованием интернет синхронизации приложений на Android, API Pusher, OpenCV, так что наверное, я не самый зеленый новичок. По крайней мере мне так кажется.

Собственно мой вопрос после этого неудачного опыта - это я пропустил какие-то основы языка, или что-то важное, или это работодатель спросил слишком сложный вопрос для вакансии Junior Python?

Comment: I'm sorry, but It is resource is intended for Russian language. Please try to use your question in English version resource: [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Прошу прощения, я не знал о том что существует русский раздел stuckoverflow, и думал что это браузер чудит и делает перевод сайта.

Comment: Это вопрос однозначно не на джуниора. Знание особенностей реализации может быть требованием к сеньору.

Comment: На самом деле зависит от того, чем занимается компания. У них могут быть специфические требования, например они работают с финансами\большими числами. Вследствие этого они хотят видеть от джуна знаний о реализации типа float. На самом деле это у них профессиональный перекос. Не переживайте, на самом деле это не вопрос для джуна.

Comment: @Max Pershin - по-моему, ужас (мне жаль, правда). Никогда не отчаивайтесь. А если вы уже впали в отчаяние, то продолжайте работать в  Python/Kivy с использованием интернет синхронизации приложений на Android, API Pusher, OpenCV. И ПОМОГИТЕ Stack Overflow возможностью оценивать вопросы и ответы, что поднимает или понижает репутацию зарегистрированных пользователей.

Comment: @MaxPershin Отвечу как человек, который собеседует кандидатов. Я бы не стал задавать такой вопрос ни джуниору, ни выше. Тем более отсеивать при незнании. У кандидата, может, ну просто не встречались в прошлой работе задачи, где это знание бы пригодилось, хоть там опыта 3 года, 5 лет, хоть сколько угодно. Ну вот не было и всё. А незнание этого нюанса, если уж это критично для компании, решается за 10 минут в первый день работы. Так что не переживайте, и успехов в поиске :)

Answer (score 3):

Краткий ответ:
[Числа с плавающей точкой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

Очень интересный и спорный вопрос был вам задан.

Знание ответа на него подразумевает одно из двух:

- Вы проходили в университете типы данных и просто запомнили;
- Вы сталкивались с ограничением точности float/double, к примеру при численном моделировании.

Практическая польза от этих знаний:

- понимание что не каждое число может быть представлено вещественным типом данных
- Арифметические операции между большим и маленькими числами могут не работать как в математике:

```
    float a = 1e-10;
    float b = 1e20;
    float c = a + b;
    cout << c == b;
```

Выведет true.